# For what value(s) of the constant k does the plane intersect the line?

Tags: linear-algebra

Plane:

```
kx - 2y + z = 0
```

Line:(Parametric equations)

```
x = 1 + kt 
y = 2 + 4t 
z = 1 - t
```

When the constant k is in both the plane and the line I cannot simply plug in the parametric equations in the plane since I will have to solve for k and t. So what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plug those in, you'll obtain:

$k(1+kt)-2(2+4t)+(1-t)=0$

or

$(k^2-9)t+(k-3)=0$

- If $k\neq\pm 3$, there is a unique solution, namely $t=\frac{3-k}{k^2-9}$, so the line intersects the plane in $1$ point.
- If $k=3$, then you have $0=0$, which is true for all $t$, so the line lies completely in the plane.
- If $k=-3$, then we have $-6=0$, which is false for all $t$, so the line must be off the plane and parallel to it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  Attempting to find the intersection, we have
$$k(1+kt)-2(2+4t)+(1-t)=0$$
which simplifies to
$$(k^2-9)t=-k+3\ .$$
For any particular value of $k$, the line and plane intersect if this equation has (one or more) solutions, and they do not intersect if the equation has no solutions.  Can you sort out the values of $k$ which give you the various possibilities?